# Why this particular youtube URL can't be embeded?

Tags: jquery, html, youtube, embed

I'm trying to integrate this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0) to my website but It does not work.

What's wrong with this ?

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Is there any error in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is nothing wrong with iframe or video i checked its working properly please show console log to clearify you issue

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Video test</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```